# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int |f_n-f|d\mu < +\infty$ implies that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ $\mu$-a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a measure space.  Let $f,f_1,f_2,\ldots:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be $\mathcal{A}$-measurable functions that are $\mu$-integrable.

Show that if
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int |f_n-f|d\mu < +\infty
\end{align}
then $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ $\mu$-a.e.

My idea is to prove the contrapositive, i.e. that if $\{f_n\}$ does not converges to $f$ $\mu$-a.e., then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int |f_n-f|d\mu = +\infty$. However, I am a bit stuck. Any hints?

Comment: If the infinite sum is finite, this implies the terms converge to $0$

Comment: Yes, this is a repost then @TheSilverDoe. I guess interchanging the sum and the integral follows from Beppo Levi's Theorem (and thus MCT) and then we get what we want.